Should I be careful about setting levels too high at one point in a track?
I have a signal processing and telecommunications background.  Because of this I feel a natural urge to not push gain high at any one point.  If I find myself in a situation where my level is very low I might insert a Utility plugin and boost it a little, then boost it a little more at the EQ, etc. until I get to my desired level.
With current DAWs and digital music production in general, is it ok to push the utility hard (in my opinion >6dB) or is staging it the best bet for minimizing noise?
Edit: It's not clipping I'm thinking about but amplification of quantization noise across the chain, non-linearities and phase noise, things like that.

In terms of music (rather than just signal), I'd be putting a compressor on the track, so that one point in the song is automatically reduced, but the rest of the track is at 'normal' levels.

TL;DR: No need to be careful. Freely mix to get the best relative levels and don't worry about gain staging
In modern DAWs, you will generally see a "clip" indication if you exceed digital Full Scale levels (0 dBFS - maximum numerical value possible at that point in the virtual signal chain), but you won't hear clipping.
I'm wondering if your question comes more from an analog perspective, however. As I'm sure you know (but I'm restating for others), with analog devices, their response usually becomes increasingly non-linear as the input signal gets closer to the limits of the device (either too high or too low). Analog devices have ideal operating points, and for the highest fidelity processing, we like to gain stage so each device receives a signal close to its ideal operating point. This can also be exploited for musical benefit by using the non-linearity as a musical effect.
I touched on that to say that by default, virtual devices in the DAW do not become increasingly non-linear as the input levels vary. They maintain complete fidelity across the entire dynamic range.
There are plenty of virtual analog processors in DAWs that are designed to recreate the non-linear characteristics of analog devices as closely as possible.
So, gain staging is a thing inside DAWs, but it's a very different thing. You don't have to work hard to find the best operating point for everything in the project. Most of the time, you can freely adjust gain without loss of fidelity unless you're using a plugin that models non-linear analog devices.
The most important place to consider levels in a DAW mix session is on the final output bus. This is a bit more of a "mastering" consideration, but you might want to be aware of how the final product will be listened to. If you're burning a CD, just don't exceed Full Scale and don't have the average level too low (16 bit quantization error is audible at high listening levels). Streaming services have recommended/desired/required RMS and peak levels, depending on the service. The point is, final delivery is definitely an appropriate time to be carefully setting levels.


It's not clipping I'm thinking about but amplification of quantization noise across the chain, non-linearities and phase noise, things like that.

In a way, quantization error is just the complement to clipping in the dynamic range continuum, so we can kind of think about everything I wrote with "all the signs reversed" - umm... sort of. Let me be clearer.
I'm about 99% sure that the only source of quantization noise in a DAW workflow is in recorded audio files. As an incoming analog signal is coded in an ADC, quantization noise will be introduced and stored based on the word length (AKA "bit depth") configured in the ADC. Likewise, if we generate audio in the digital domain and write that audio to a file, the file format will have a bit depth for its encoding and so that file will have a fixed quantization noise recorded in it.
I don't believe anything that is purely quantization noise is introduced in processing in DAWs. I'm pretty sure all modern DAWs (possibly excluding free ones) have 32-bit or even 64-bit floating-point processing. While the quantization error can never be non-zero, in such systems it's so far below audible that we would have to work very hard and deliberately to make even barely audible.
Assuming your ADC and your file formats are using at least 24-bit integer words, that's also a very low noise floor that you generally don't have to worry about. Another way to think about it is the analog noise introduced by components after the DAC used in reproduction will be greater than any quantization error introduced by 24-bit integers sampling. It is also common to be able to store audio in 32-bit floating file formats if you're really looking for the lowest possible noise floor.
That's not to say that you can just have arbitrarily low levels followed by massive amounts of gain and not hear any consequences, but there's a lot more leeway for gain staging in a modern DAW than there is in the analog world.

Thank you for the info.  I added some clarification to the question based on your input.

I'm not sure what the question really is, but I'll answer anyway.
If you mean, "will I destroy my signal if my levels get too high somewhere along the signal path", then the answer is almost always no, because most DAWs, including Ableton Live, and the plugins inside them use floating point numbers everywhere on the signal path, and floating point numbers do not clip in any actual practical scenario. Only audio coming from outside via external audio inputs, and audio going outside the DAW, via audio export or external audio outputs, is in integer numbers that can clip.
With floating point numbers, you can have fantastically loud signals on the signal path, like hundreds of dB above "full scale", but there is no clipping, you can attenuate with the same amount and get the signal back below 0 dBFS. The VU meters may be all red and show +100 dB, but you did not clip. Only when exporting to integer world, like a WAV or MP3 file, or for external audio outputs, you need to make sure your signal is within limits.
But even if you can't clip inside the DAW, it is good practice to maintain reasonable levels, to be able to keep things in control. If all your meters show "TOO LOUD", the meters are useless and you're in trouble when trying to bring it down to manageable levels on the master bus. And by thinking about gain staging you're already doing everything correctly.
In short: don't worry, you're doing fine.

I learned recently that Ableton Live actually clips audio internally at around +64dBFS, rather than allowing the full +~700dBFS maximum that 32-bit audio can represent.

@Edward Interesting! I wonder what the rationale is for that feature, as it must have been deliberately programmed in. I guess few people discover the limit, because once you go above +0, things get increasingly difficult to manage, and it's just common sense to avoid that.

@piiperiReinstateMonica Might be to let some headroom for AL 's internal processing (to avoid changing to a double precision type) (or just to force users to have good practices;) )

A new separate answer, because after re-reading with the OP's edit, I think I misunderstood the question in my first one. I'll leave the other answer, because the question CAN be seen that way.

If I find myself in a situation where my level is very low I might
insert a Utility plugin and boost it a little, then boost it a little
more at the EQ, etc. until I get to my desired level.


Edit: It's not clipping I'm thinking about but amplification of
quantization noise across the chain, non-linearities and phase noise,
things like that.

Let me paraphrase. You're thinking that in DAWs, it might be bad to make a large single gain change, and if it would perhaps be better to do multiple small gain changes instead.
Quantization noise in modern DAWs is only introduced in analog-to-digital conversions (and when exporting audio to integer audio data formats with less precision than the DAW has internally). After recording analog sound to a file in a DAW, whatever noise was introduced in the process, is a part of the signal you have in the audio file. When amplifying the signal inside the DAW, the noise is amplified as well. If you amplify by, say, 10 dB, it doesn't matter if you do it in one step of 10 dB or 10 steps of 1 dB. The signal, including the  quantization noise it contains, is amplified by 10 dB.
Gain stages in a floating-point based DAW, such as Ableton Live, do not add quantization noise in the conventional meaning of the word, because the signal is not quantized. What does get added to the signal is very small rounding errors of the floating point numbers, which you could consider being like quantization noise as well, but I think it's better to keep the concepts separate.
Mixing i.e. summing in a digital audio system is an addition (sum) operation, and a gain change is a multiplication operation. Depending on the operands, the result of a multiplication may contain more bits i.e. significant digits than fits in the result, so the result has to be rounded. In integer-based systems, when the results of multiplications get smaller and closer to zero, more bits of precision are lost. But with floating point numbers, the rounding error in multiplication is limited to the smallest bit of the mantissa. In summing i.e. addition, integer-based math does not lose precision, but floating point math can (in theory) do so, if the summed values are of very different magnitude.
So to answer the question "will splitting a large gain change to several small gain changes result in less quantization noise in Ableton Live", the answer is no, it's the other way around. One gain change will introduce only one rounding error, but multiple gain changes will introduce multiple rounding errors.
Does that matter? In all practical cases, for the end-user, no. If you were programming your own DAW system, you should understand the math and consider precision loss in various operations. It's good to try and minimize the number of operations, maybe think about the ordering of operations, and use wider data types with more bits of precision for intermediate results.
One more thing if you're interested in gain changes and rounding errors. In floating point based DAWs, multiplying by exact powers of 2, including 1/2, 1/4 etc., is a special case which does not introduce any rounding errors, because the multiplication only changes the exponent, and the mantissa is kept exactly the same. If you want to make absolutely transparent gain changes, that's the way to do it. :) So how to do that in Ableton Live? Since Ableton's user interface uses decibel values for specifying gain changes, you'd have to use too many digits like +6.02059991327962390440 dB, so that won't work. But you could try using the free and open source BitShiftGain plugin by Airwindows. https://www.airwindows.com/bitshiftgain/
A BitShiftGain of 2 bits looks like this in Ableton Live:

Many other plugins and components for CLAP, VST3, AU, LV2 and VCV Rack:
https://www.airwindows.com/vsts/
https://github.com/airwindows/airwindows

Why would you not consider the quantization noise that is introduced after every DSP transformation to be quantization noise?  Also, you should frontload the important info:  "Does that matter? In all practical cases, for the end-user, no."

@Edward Nah, I'm tired, I don't feel it's worth it to try and change the answer, it is what it is.
